# insert data to the database, and then get an autogenerated int key in return

Tags: php, mysqli

Couldn't find a method like the [int executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in php.

I want to insert data to the database, and then get an autogenerated int key in return (the ID).

Thanks :)

Oh, and PS: it has to be a method from the mysqli class =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`mysql_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id):

> `mysql_insert_id` — Get the ID generated
>   from the previous INSERT operation

Example (from the manual):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

To retrieve the last auto-generated key using `mysqli`, see [`mysqli->insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: thanks. but I forgot to say that I can only use the mysqli class

Comment: I can see now that this method is also available in the mysqli.. thanks a lot ;)